# ¿Cómo dar formato a números mientras se está escribiendo?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Quiero realizar una especie de `Plugin` que **formatea** a las **cifras numéricas** mientras se va escribiendo. Pero no lo he logrado, hay un pequeño detalle y no sé cómo resolverlo.

Ejemplo:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        var caja = sender as TextBox;

        //Permite solo ingreso de números y puntos            
        e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != '.');
        //Permite solo aceptar un punto
        e.Handled = (e.KeyChar == '.') && (caja.Text.IndexOf('.') > -1);
        

        if (caja.Text != "")
        {
            double v = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(caja.Text), 2);
            caja.Text = string.Format("{0:0,0.00}", v);
            
            //Si ejecuto este messagebox, sí me imprime el número con su formato correcto "1,234.45"
            //Si pongo "5" imprime "05.00" y con 20 "20.00", sí hace bien su trabajo,
            //Pero cuando lo imprimo en el textBox da formatos extraños.
            //MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0:0,0.00}", 1234.4567));
        }
    }
```

Y una duda, alguien me podría explicar la`condicional` que permite solo números y puntos, paso a paso, ya que no la entendí del todo:

```
e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != '.');
```

Gracias.

Comment: Podrías usar un https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask%28v=vs.110%29.aspx en lugar de un TextBox y santo remedio...

Comment: Lo que pasa es que estoy utilizando paquetes `Nuget` para los estilos de los `TextBox`, y pues no contrastaría si mezclo dos tipos de `TextBox`

Comment: ¿Cuál es ese paquete de nuget?

Comment: Uso el Material Skin, y en ese paquete no se encuentra el MaskTextBox

Comment: esta pregunta ya fue hecha en SO en ingles https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671148/textbox-display-formatting